# how come facebook, twitter and others, do not open any request for security certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am currently trying to figure out how does OCSP protocol works.
what traffic is sent/ received and from whom.

as for my current understanding  when a client tries to address a server, a request to a 3rd party is being done(**a new stream to a new address**), this is the ocsp responder which gets his information from the certificate authority who issued the certificate.
then a feedback returns which is an ocsp response what matches the RFC.

2 questions

- is the stream for the 3rd party always done over http ore is it done
  over ssl to ? if it is done over ssl how can I recognize it?
- when using Facebook or twitter I see only one main stream, and no request to a 3rd party even thought deleting all the cookies and cash. any explanation?

thanks !
shlomi

Comment: How would you see a request from Facebook etc to an OCSP from a client?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, it's more suitable for http://security.stackexchange.com or Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. During the validation of a certificate with OCSP (actually it is also true for CRL) the client sends a request to third party server called *OCSP responder*. Most of the time, the URL where the request must be send can be found in the certificate *Authority Information Access* extension.

The OCSP request sent by the client contains an unique identifier for a certificate composed of its serial number, the hash of the certificate issuer DN and the hash of the issuer public key.

The OCSP response contains a validation status which could be:

- GOOD: the certificate is valid
- REVOKED: the certificate has been revoked at some point in the past
- UNKNWON: the OCSP responder does not have the information to determine the current revocation status of the certificate

There is no mandatory transport protocol defined by OCSP but HTTP is used most of the time. OCSP responses are signed therefore they cannot be tampered and an additional security layer (for instance TLS) is not required.

There are numerous reasons which could explain the fact thah you do not see the connection to the OCSP server:

- your client does not check the validation status of the SSL certificates
- your client prefers using CRL validation over OCSP and keeps a copy of a *still valid* CRL.
- your client tries to contact the OCSP server but the connection is blocked by a firewall or a proxy
- ...

Answer (score 1):

OCSP requests can be done in two ways:

- connect to the SSL server, get the certificate + chain and check the certifcate(s) for an OCSP URL. Then send an OCSP query to this URL (which can be http, https and others) and check response.
- use OCSP stapling. In this case the OCSP response for the SSL servers certificate is requested from the SSL server within the initial SSL handshake. To support SSL stapling the server requests the (signed) OCSP response for its certifcate from time to time from the original OCSP server and can then attach it to the SSL handshake. Because the OCSP response is attached to the initial SSL handshake you will not see a seperate request for it.